# MySQL Two tables Count and display

Tags: mysql

I have a tables:

```
ogloszenie
Id | id_kat
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
...


kategoria
Id_kat | Name
1        Test1
2        Test2
3        Tesy3
4        Test4
...
```

My query:

```
SELECT kategoria.Name, count(ogloszenie.Id_kategoria) AS ile
FROM ogloszenie INNER JOIN kategoria ON ogloszenie.id_kat = kategoria.Id_kat
GROUP BY kategoria.Id_kat;
```

When i run this query display only rows where id_kat is in table 'ogloszenie'

```
Test1 3
Test2 1
```

I need display:

```
Test1 3
Test2 1
Test3 0 
Test4 0
```

Comment: You need to read about different types of join - and INNER JOIN means the value must exist in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  kategoria.Name, 
        COUNT(ogloszenie.Id_kat) as iCount
FROM    kategoria left join ogloszenie
        ON kategoria.Id_kat = ogloszenie.Id_kat
GROUP BY  kategoria.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kategoria.Name, count(IFNULL(ogloszenie.Id_kategoria, 0)) AS ile
FROM kategoria
LEFT JOIN ogloszenie ON ogloszenie.id_kat = kategoria.Id_kat
GROUP BY kategoria.Id_kat;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` means that you take the `kategoria` id's as the base ones instead of the `ogloszenie` `Id_kat`'s.

Either that, or

```
FROM ogloszenie
RIGHT JOIN kategoria ...
```